# Uploading image from UIImageView to Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to upload images to Parse.com with image text, upload time and username for the person that uploads the image, sometimes it works, but most of the time it does not work.

[image]

As you can see where it says "uploaded_image.png", it successfully uploaded everything with the image, but on the row at the top, the image did not get uploaded.

It looks that when i upload a image from the camera roll it takes 3-5 seconds, and the image get successfully uploaded, but when I try to take photo, and upload the photo taken at that point, it does not work..

Here is my full UploadViewController.swift code, hope I can get som tips:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import Social
import Photos
import PhotosUI

class UploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var uploadingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadingText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var uploadButton: UIButton!

    var tabBarItemONE: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem()
    var tabBarItemTWO: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.imageText.delegate = self

        uploadButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        uploadButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        uploadButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        uploadButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if (imageView.image == nil)
        {
            var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: "How would you like to upload a photo?.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take photo", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.takePhoto()
            }))

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose existing photo", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.chooseExistingPhoto()
            }))

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Never mind", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.resetViewController()
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            }))

            presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += 200
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func uploadButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        uploadingView.hidden = false
        uploadingText.hidden = false
        uploadPost()
    }
    func uploadPost(){
        var imageText = self.imageText.text

        if (imageView.image == nil){
            println("No image uploaded")
        }
        else{
            disableTabBarItems()
            var posts = PFObject(className: "Posts")
            currentUploads["imageText"] = imageText
            currentUploads["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
            currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    //**Success saving, now save image.**//

                    // Create an image data
                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)
                    // Create a parse file to store in cloud
                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData)
                    currentUploads["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                    currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            // Take user home
                            self.enableTabBarItems()
                            println(success)
                            println("Data uploaded")
                            self.resetViewController()
                            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                            self.showSuccessUpload()
                        }
                        else{
                            println(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{
                    println(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func disableTabBarItems(){
        let tabBarControllerItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items

        if let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarControllerItems as! AnyObject as? NSArray{

            tabBarItemONE = arrayOfTabBarItems[0] as! UITabBarItem
            tabBarItemONE.enabled = false

            tabBarItemTWO = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as! UITabBarItem
            tabBarItemTWO.enabled = false

        }
    }

    func enableTabBarItems(){
        tabBarItemONE.enabled = true
        tabBarItemTWO.enabled = true
    }

    func takePhoto(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func chooseExistingPhoto(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        imageView.image = image
        let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
        let hasAlpha = false
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showSuccessUpload(){
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Message"
        alert.message = "Your photo has been uploaded."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
    }

    func resetViewController(){
        imageView.image = nil
        imageText.text = nil
        uploadingView.hidden = true
        uploadingText.hidden = true
    }
}
```

EDIT: I see now in the log output, it shows some kind of warning:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Any suggestions what to do here? How should the code be?

Answer (score 0):

I found that image files don't update reliably when they are uploaded via cellular data rather than WiFi and when they are fairly large.  I reduce the images from the camera roll to 25%, which I believe is your scale value.  I use obj-c, so my code looks a bit different...

Here's some of my relevant code sample, with commented out output lines that helped compare the size of these images to figure out what scale was appropriate.  Notice the last thing I do is sleep for 2 seconds to ensure that the imageFile was created properly.

```
    // For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{
    NSLog(@"hit use photo");
    float compressionRatio = 0.25;
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {

        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                   UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) 
        {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, compressionRatio);
//        NSLog(@"imageData length after compression of 1.0: %d", [imageData length]);
//        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, .5);
//        NSLog(@"imageData length after compression of 0.5: %d", [imageData length]);
//        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, .25);
//        NSLog(@"imageData length after compression of 0.25: %d", [imageData length]);

        imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"completedJob%@.JPEG", _homeView.currentJob.objectId] data:imageData];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```